# Selenium Unclicable button Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have an issue when trying to click this button in Selinium:
[image]

The folloying is the html code for each side:

"plus de 26 ans"

[image]

"Moins de 26 ans"

[image]

I have tride creating a button clicker by id using selenium (for first button):

```
btn_date = driver.find_element_by_id("radio-ins_age-above_26")
btn_date.click()
```

I get the error message that it is not clickable.

However, when viewing the html when I switch from one button to other I get the following change:

First button:

[image]

There is "::after::" that appears. When I click or press anything else it disappears.

How can I click this button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on dynamic element use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for element to be clickable.
Use the following `xpath` to click.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(.,'Plus de 26')]"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(.,'Moins de 26')]"))).click()
```

Import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thanks that did it. I was trying to select field by xpath and do an arrow left or right to select, but was not working.